# How to send selected id in parameter using actionURL?

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, portlet, portal

Here is my view.jsp:

```
<portlet:actionURL name="getTravelId" var="travelIdUrl">
</portlet:actionURL>
for (Travel t : list) {
    <a href="<%=travelIdUrl%>"><%=t.getId() %></a>
}
```

Then in the class:

```
 @ProcessAction(name="getTravelId")
        public void getSelectedTravelId(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){

        String idTravel = request.getParameter("idTravel");

        System.out.println("TRAVEL ID: " + idTravel);

    }
```

I tried sending the parameter like:

```
  <a href="<%=travelIdUrl%>?travelId="<%=t.getId()%>""><%=t.getId() %></a>
```

but not working.

Also tried putting the actionURL inside for, still not working

```
 for (Travel t : list) {
 <portlet:actionURL name="getTravelId" var="travelIdUrl">
        <portlet:param name="idTravel" value="<%t.getId()%>"/>
    </portlet:actionURL>
 <a href="<%=travelIdUrl%>"><%=t.getId() %></a>
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were definitely on the right path using the `<portlet:param>` tag to add parameters to a portlet URL. Perhaps you can try using more JSTL and fewer scriptlets. Try something more like the code snippet below.

```
<c:forEach items='${list}' var="travel">
    <portlet:actionURL name="getTravelId" var="travelIdUrl">
        <portlet:param name="idTravel" value="${travel.id}"/>
    </portlet:actionURL>
    <a href="${travelIdUrl}">${travel.id}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it will create N no of URL.where N is the size of list.

Comment: @Gautam you're right it will create a URL for each item in the list. But that appeared to be what the question was asking for; an anchor tag for each item in the list. I haven't done any performance testing to see if creating one URL and then appending the individual parameter is faster than a new URL for each item, but I have had problems appending parameters like that before.

Answer (score 1):

what exactly did not work in your last example? I think you are mixing Java code with HTML and tags. Try this example in your JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="t" items="${list}">
  <portlet:actionURL name="getTravelId" var="travelIdUrl">
    <portlet:param name="idTravel" value="${t.id}"/>
  </portlet:actionURL>
 <a href="${travelIdUrl}">${t.id}</a>
</c:forEach>
```

It creates an anchor for each item in `list` with given id parameter. The example uses only HTML and tags and JSP expresion language for accessing variables.

Comment: That's the answer. Thank you!